# the best way to add custom button on tabbar center

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

when I use way to custom button like this [What's the best way of adding a custom centre button to a tab bar?](http://mobile-patterns.com/custom-tab-navigation)

```
[tabbarcontroller.view addsubview:button]
```

to add custom button on the view ,the navigationcontroller push to other viewController will use the method `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to hide the tabbar , but the button would stay on screen

or I use this `[tabbarcontroller.tabBar addsubview:button]` way to add on tabbar ,but my button would covered by the tabbar and can not receive the touch event.

please tell me the way  to fix it ,and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your first option is that it's not hiding ? If so, you can hide it manually.

Comment: so you want the button to move lower ?

Comment: I want to add a button on the tabbar,and higher than the tabbar,when I push to other view controller it should be hide together

Comment: can you upload your project ?

Comment: sorry i'm poor at English ,but you can look the image in this page http://ourcoders.com/thread/show/4769/ that's what I mean "the button be covered by tabbar"

Comment: if I get it right. You want the tabbar above the view ? Try this.
    [tabbar].layer.zposition = 1;

Comment: if you want the button above the tabbar, you can use it again. button.layer.zposition = 2;

Comment: I know ,it working.I just click the 'enter' button without finish my works. you should edit your answer and I will accept it

Comment: I want to ask one more question,I use ` [tabbarcontroller.tabBar addsubview:button]` to add buttom on the tabbar, than the button can not receive the touch event

Comment: if your asking me if it cannot receive it, i don't know. but if not. you can use tag gesture.

Comment: OK，I try the other way